# Issue in my rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem in my rails controller that my index, show pages won't be appearing in my server, this is my code in controller:

```
 class GamesController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @games=Game.all

        @render_carousel = true
      end

      def new
        @game=Game.new

      end

      def create
        @game=Game.new(game_params)
        if @game.save
          flash[:notice] = 'game created'
          redirect_to games_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def edit
        @game=Game.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @game=Game.find(params[:id])
        if @game.update(game_params)
          flash[:notice] = 'game updated'
          redirect_to games_path
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @game=Game.find(params[:id])
        @game.destroy(game_params)
          flash[:notice] = 'game deleted'
          redirect_to games_path
      end

      def show
        @game=Game.find(params[:id])
      end
      private

      def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:name, :year, :description, :price, :category_id, :creator_id,:coverpath)
      end
    end
```

This is my index page code: I get the error in link_to line, and the error is in index and show page

```
<div id="page-index">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <div class="thumbnail">
           <%= image_tag('cover/un1.jpg')%>
            <h4><b>Uncharted</b></h4>
            <p>The Uncharted series is one of the best action adventure franchises in recent gaming history,
              </p>
            <%= link_to 'Read More' ,@game_path(game), class:'btn btn-primary'%>
        <div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
<%= link_to 'Read More', game_path(game), class:'btn btn-primary'%>
```

or, just this:

```
<%= link_to 'Read More', game, class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
```

Both should work as long as `game` is actually present in the database.

#### Update

Loop through the `@games` and show the each game link in your `index.html.erb` file:

```
<% @games.each do |game| %>
  <%= link_to 'Read More', game_path(game), class:'btn btn-primary'%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I did the second method and it's not working 
the first method error is : No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"games", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Yeah, because the `game` is not present in the DB. Can you paste the full `index.html` code?

Comment: I already insert the date in the database and the index page I already posted in my post

Comment: @anna97 You're welcome. I am glad I could help you solve the issue.